# Error using scanner class for reading .txt

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

i am working on a program to read a binary file and update it form a txt file, it was working the all of a sudden it started throwing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at StockManage.updateInv(StockManage.java:134)
    at StockManage.main(StockManage.java:173)
```

heres the code thats causes the error

```
try
{
    Scanner trans = new Scanner(new File(file));
    RandomAccessFile inv = new RandomAccessFile (file2,"rws");
    String tempName = "Temp" + (int)(Math.random()*1000000) + ".dat";
    RandomAccessFile newInv = new RandomAccessFile (tempName , "rws");
    File newFile = new File(tempName);

    String transISBN = trans.next();
    String author = inv.readUTF();
    String title = inv.readUTF();
    String iSBN = inv.readUTF();
    int amount = inv.readInt();

    while (inv.getFilePointer()<=inv.length())
    {
        boolean empty = true;

        while (empty&&trans.hasNext())
        {

            if (iSBN.compareTo(transISBN)<0)
            {
                empty = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (iSBN.compareTo(transISBN)==0)
            {
                int change = trans.nextInt();
                amount += change;
                transISBN = trans.next();
            }
        }

        newInv.writeUTF(author);
        newInv.writeUTF(title);
        newInv.writeUTF(iSBN);
        newInv.writeInt(amount);

        author = inv.readUTF();
        title = inv.readUTF();
        iSBN = inv.readUTF();
        amount = inv.readInt();


    }
```

im really stuck in this one so any help would be great

Comment: It would be useful to point out which line StockManage.java:134 is so we can get an idea of where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code part is error-prone:

```
else if (iSBN.compareTo(transISBN)==0)
{
    int change = trans.nextInt();
    amount += change;
    transISBN = trans.next();
}
```

You control `trans.hasNext()` in the `while loop`, but you don't before `transISBN = trans.next();` put an `if(trans.hasNext())` at the top of it and problem will be solved, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling next() on a Scanner object you should call hasNext() to check if there is actually more data to read.